# Zone.js has high CPU usage even when idle

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

I have a question about zone.js in Angular. I have built an electron application using Angular (which uses zone.js), and it turns out that when the application is running, it uses up to 15% of the CPU, even though I am not doing anything in the app. If I minimize the app, the CPU usage goes down to normal (1-2%). I believe this is happening because of zone.js, since it handles things like setTimeout and other async operations. Is this a known issue? Is this expected? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Could you provide a reproduce repo?

Answer (score -2):

i think this is issue by some predefined event are called by automatically Angular  like